# How to post files from Linux, viewable from an old device that cannot log into SharePoint?

Tags: html, login, storage, file-server

My workplace provides me with a [Microsoft 365 Business Standard account](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/business/compare-all-microsoft-365-business-products).

I have a Linux computer that just sits in the corner, creating an HTML page with some simple, yet important alerts. The HTML page contains this code, to refresh it every ten seconds:

```
<html>
<script>
    window.setInterval('refresh()', 10000);     
    function refresh() {
        window .location.reload();
    }
</script>
<blinking>Warning, temperature exceeds 600 kelvin!</blinking>
</html>
```

Meanwhile, I have another device, based on Android 2.1, and not-upgradable, that just retrieves and displays the page, refreshing every it 10 seconds. The Linux computer script will upload a new file if a change in message is needed, and then the Android device will display the new message the next time the 10-second refresh is run.

NOTE: The Android 2.1 device browser cannot be upgraded further, and it cannot log into Microsoft 365's account, so it needs to be able to read the file from SharePoint/similar storage without logging in.

Is there somewhere within Microsoft tools where I can both (1) upload a file via BASH to be stored in the Microsoft tools (e.g. SharePoint or OneDrive or similar) and (2) that is viewable without requiring a password, from the old Android device?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Graph API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) to [Upload the File](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-upload-a-new-file) to your OneDrive. You could then create an [anonymous sharing link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request). This link could then be opend from your Android device. The downside of this would be that everyone that has this link can open the file